# Is it possible to change the file extension for an older version of a S3 object?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

The original file version is `.png`

Is there a way I can rename version 0's key from `image.png` to `image.gif`?

````
version: 1,
fileName: 'image.gif',
id: 'uqwQEUW'
}

{
version: 0,
fileName: 'image.png',
id: 'uqwQEUW'
}```
````

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow - I've updated your question to make it clearer based on what I think you meant. Feel free to change again if I've misunderstood. For future questions, I'd recommend reading https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask if you already haven't :)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no simple way to change the key of an S3 object and preserve its version history.

You can create the .gif object and iterate through the versions of the .png to preserve png versions under the .gif key

Answer (score 0):

there's another way you can save the file in the format in which you wanted, than again re-upload the file and make versioning available on the s3 bucket, than s3 will keep the current version and you can also delete the versions from s3.

Answer (score 0):

The `Key` of an object in Amazon S3 is its unique identifier. There is no concept of 'renaming' objects in Amazon S3.

You would need to **copy** the object to a different Key. This would make it a new object without impacting the original object.